# Click on notification and then go to next detail page where there is also the detail of that are present

Tags: android

I am the student of computer science last semester student.
I have problem:
I set my Android Application that receive notification from online database of job finder web application.When new entry occur then notification comes here on Android App.
So now i want if i click that notification then there will be a page open in which the detail of that job will present.

so please guid me i have only few days to submit my final year project.
I will be very thankfull.

Comment: [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm) Crux: `Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);`

Comment: Look at `PendingIntent`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html). There they describe to set up a `PendingIntent` to react to the click on the notification.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
...
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent); // Code comes directly from this Developer Guide
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Pending Intent to open page when click on Notification.

```
// prepare intent which is triggered if the
// notification is selected

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityToBeOpen.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

You can find more details [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

To create Notification :

```
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,
    "Android Example Status message!",
    System.currentTimeMillis());

// This pending intent will open after notification click
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotifyMessage.class);
PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Android Example Notification Title",
    "This is the android example notification message", i);

// After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
// note.number=2;
mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
```

---

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotifyMessage.class);
PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
```

Its manage  your navigation after click on notification. If you want no navigation then use :

```
Intent i = new Intent();
PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Hey , My Notification Starts From a background Services , How to Start my Activity From A Service ?
I have tried your code but on Click it Dosnt Open my desired View (NotificationView.class)